# How to track Social Interaction with Google Analytics in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, tracking

Someone can advice on how to track social interaction with google analytics in Drupal 7

Some links, tutos...

Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analytic Custom variables

- [Tracking Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)
- [Mastering Google Analytics Custom Variables](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/18/mastering-google-analytics-custom-variables/)